# Remove First n Lines of a Large Text File

Tags: command-line

I need to remove the first 42 lines of a 2GB SQL dump.

I know I can view the first lines using:

```
head -n 44 dump.sql
```

But is there anyway to edit or remove them?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This seems to be the easiest:

```
sed '1,42d' test.sql > test2.sql
```

Remove lines 1-42 from test.sql and save as test2.sql

Comment: a shorter one would be **sed -i '1,42d' test.sql** if you don't need to keep the original file.

Answer (score 152):

If you want to just *view* the lines from the 43rd on you can use

```
tail -n +43 dump.sql
```

The `+` sign is important - without it, `tail` will print the *last* 43 lines instead. Alternatively with 'sed'

```
sed 1,42d dump.sql
```

If you want to really delete the first 42 lines from the original file then you can make sed make the change inplace with the `-i` option

```
sed -i 1,42d dump.sql
```

Comment: Awesome answer, fantastic use of `tail`. I found many times something new to learn from your answers. thanks.

Comment: Oh man tail -n +43 is a game changer! I've been using an awkward invocation of sed to the same effect.

Comment: What if you have no space left on device? `sed -i 1,50000000d 17GigFile` creates a temp file `sedXYZ` that consumes many more gigabytes. Is there an approach without temp files?

Comment: What's the difference between `tail -n +43` and `head -n 44` as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @juanmf You might try to do this with a gui tool (I've done it using Mousepad, but the file of interest was "only" ~700MB.  Takes awhile for the file to load, though...

Answer (score 13):

try this,

`tail -n +43 dump.sql > dump_new.sql`

Answer (score 9):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -s -c '1d42|x' dump.sql
```

1. `1` move to first line
2. `42` select 42 lines
3. `d` delete
4. `x` save and close

Comment: Does it create a temp file? Is it possible to do this when space left on device is less than file size?

Comment: @juanmf All these solutions require a temporary file. It is only possible to remove data from _the end_ of a file without using a temporary file.

Comment: @PerlDuck could you please elaborate on why (or link ressource) "It is only possible to remove data from the end of a file without using a temporary file" ?

Answer (score 2):

Because of `sed` discrepancies across Linux and Mac, I resolved to use `tail -n +43 dump.sql > new.sql` format.

Comment: Won't work becuase `> dump.sql` is interpreted by the shell _before_ `tail ... dump.sql` reads the file, i.e. the file is flushed before `tail` opens it, hence the file is completely empty after that command.

Comment: @PerlDuck I must have probably used another file name at the time of writing this. This should work. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add this. If you're on a mac you need to add the backup extension. Answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247319/808603).

```
sed -i '.bak' 1,42d dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't give you actual code right now.
However, try looking at something along the lines of

```
tail -n arcv(`wc -l`) -44
```

What this should do (once properly formatted) is count the number of lines in the file (wc -l), subtract 44 from it (-44) and then print out everything starting with the 45th line in the file.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: This is not quite optimal,calling `wc -l` on the file, you process it twice, whereas `sed` or `tail` process it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```bsh
head -n 42 dump.sql > tmp; cat dump.sql | grep -vxf tmp > dump.sql.new; rm tmp
```

or,

```bsh
a=$(cat dump.sql| wc -l); tail -n "$((a-42))" dump.sql > dump.sql.new
```